# Java HttpURLConnection InputStream.close() hangs (or works too long?)

Tags: java, http, tcp, httpurlconnection

**First, some background.** There is a worker which expands/resolves bunch of short URLS:

```
http://t.co/example -> http://example.com
```

So, we just follow redirects. That's it. We don't read any data from the connection. Right after we got 200 we return the final URL and close InputStream.

**Now, the problem itself.** On a production server one of the resolver threads hangs inside the `InputStream.close()` call:

```
"ProcessShortUrlTask" prio=10 tid=0x00007f8810119000 nid=0x402b runnable [0x00007f882b044000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.skip(BufferedInputStream.java:352)
        - locked <0x0000000561293aa0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.skip(MeteredStream.java:134)
        - locked <0x0000000561293a70> (a sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream)
        at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:76)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:155)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:2735)
        at ru.twitter.times.http.URLProcessor.resolve(URLProcessor.java:131)
        at ru.twitter.times.http.URLProcessor.resolve(URLProcessor.java:55)
        at ...
```

After a brief research, I understood that `skip()` is called to clean up the stream before sending it back to the connections pool (if keep-alive is set on?). Still I don't understand how to avoid this situation. Moreover, I doubt if there is some bad design in our code or there is problem in JDK.

So, the questions are:

1. Is it possible to avoid hanging on `close()`? Guarantee some reasonable
   timeout, for example.
2. Is it possible to avoid reading data from connection at all?
   Remember I just want the final URL. Actually, I think, I don't want
   `skip()` to be called at all ...

**Update:**

[KeepAliveStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/http/KeepAliveStream.java/), line 79, `close()` method:

```
    // Skip past the data that's left in the Inputstream because
    // some sort of error may have occurred.
    // Do this ONLY if the skip won't block. The stream may have
    // been closed at the beginning of a big file and we don't want
    // to hang around for nothing. So if we can't skip without blocking
    // we just close the socket and, therefore, terminate the keepAlive
    // NOTE: Don't close super class
    try {
        if (expected > count) {
        long nskip = (long) (expected - count);
        if (nskip <= available()) {
            long n = 0;
            while (n < nskip) {
            nskip = nskip - n;
            n = skip(nskip);} ...
```

More and more it seems to me that there is a bug in JDK itself. Unfortunately, it's very hard to reproduce this ...

Comment: Have you tried working directly with the InputStream instead of with a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: Stream is returned from the HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() call. I don't control it.

Comment: I see. Ok, was just a shot into the blue.

Comment: Can you use `HEAD` instead of `GET`?

Comment: Yes, we can in some cases use HEAD as very good optimization. No, we can't completely get rid of GET. For two reasons. First, not every site supports HEAD. Second, we need to emulate browser behavior as much as possible. Even if some site supports HEAD it may return something different from GET.

Comment: I'm confused. URL-shorteners return a 30x redirect code, the `Location:` header, and *no body*. `t.co` for example returns `Content-Length: 0`. So can't you just read the entire stream (of 0 bytes) before closing it?

Comment: Ah, is HttpURLConnection automatically following the redirect? Can you try `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` ?

Comment: With most URL shorteners we can even use `HEAD`, I think. The problem is that we need to follow redirects for ordinary sites either. Some of them perform redirects for one or another reason. So, in general case you will have `GET` for some ordinary site in the end. And seems that JDK behaves strangely for some of these site.

Comment: Yes, we can try to set follow-redirects to `false` and follow them manually. But it's very very hard to reproduce this hang (in a year this is the second case I see). What do you expect from this change? Why should it affect the `close()` behavior?

Comment: One of our server applications encountered the same issue while invoking a Hessian service: http://pastebin.com/TiDcNk9C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of `KeepAliveStream` that you have linked, violates the contract under which `available()` and `skip()` are guaranteed to be non-blocking and thus may indeed block.

[The contract of available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) guarantees a **single** non-blocking `skip()`:

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next
>   caller of a method for this input stream. The next caller might be
>   the same thread or another thread.  A single read or skip of this
>   many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

Wheres the implementation calls `skip()` multiple times per single call to `available()`:

```
    if (nskip <= available()) {
        long n = 0;
        // The loop below can iterate several times,
        // only the first call is guaranteed to be non-blocking. 
        while (n < nskip) { 
        nskip = nskip - n;
        n = skip(nskip);
        }
```

This doesn't prove that your application blocks because `KeepAliveStream` incorrectly uses `InputStream`. Some implementations of `InputStream` may possibly provide stronger non-blocking guarantees, but I think it is a very likely suspect.

EDIT: After a bit more research, this is a very recently fixed bug in JDK: [https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8004863?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8004863?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel). The bug report says about an infinite loop, but a blocking `skip()` could also be a result. The fix seems to address both issues (there is only a single `skip()` per `available()`)

Comment: Thank you, Jan. Indeed this is a very plausible explanation. Do you know if there is practice of backporting in the JDK dev community? Is there any chance to have this fixed in JDK6/7?

Comment: @Shcheklein according to this site http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html 'Java SE releases are updated with bug fixes, security fixes, and minor updates for a period of at least 3 years ...'. This period ends Feb 2013 for Java 6, but Java 7 should receive bug fixes until July 2014. It is unclear to me while this particular fix is market v8, perhaps it is considered too low priority (P4). Maybe it would help if you commented on the bug and explained that it was encountered in real life application and whether they plan to fix v7, because according to the policy they should.

Comment: The code you show is in close(), and contract of close() does not guarantee non-blocking.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this `skip()` on `close()` is intended for Keep-Alive support.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html.

> Prior to Java SE 6, if an application closes a HTTP InputStream when
>   more than a small amount of data remains to be read, then the
>   connection had to be closed, rather than being cached. Now in Java SE
>   6, the behavior is to read up to 512 Kbytes off the connection in a
>   background thread, thus allowing the connection to be reused. The
>   exact amount of data which may be read is configurable through the
>   `http.KeepAlive.remainingData` system property.

So keep alive can be effectively disabled with `http.KeepAlive.remainingData=0` or `http.keepAlive=false`. 
But this can negatively affect performance if you always address to the same http://t.co host.

As @artbristol suggested, using HEAD instead of GET seems to be the preferable solution here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the `remainingData` option. It's good to know. Though the problem is not solved. Moreover, I completely don't understand why `close()` hangs. Documentation says: read up to 512 kbytes in a background thread. Even if site so slow that it can't give us 512 kbytes in two days how can "background" thread hang the application?

Comment: Yes, we don't want to completely disable connections cache (we knew about `keepAlive=false` and some other cache settings which allow to turn it off). See also my comment to @artbristol about HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue when I was trying to make a "HEAD" request. To fix it, I removed the "HEAD" method because I just wanted to ping the url