# java inputstream hangs when closing

Tags: java

I need to know what could cause the `InputStream` to hang indefinitely on `close`. Here's my code.

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://..");
InputSream is = url.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(is));

try{
    while(true){
        if(reader.readline() == null){
            break;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    System.out.println("Closing reader");
    is.close(); // sometimes hangs indefinitely
    System.out.println("Reader closed");
}
```

Closing `InputStream` or `BufferedReader` has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know what could cause the InputStream to hang indefinitely on close

I think it is the nature of the particular input stream that you are using.

You have a stream open to a read a file from an FTP server.  Depending on the protocol driver that is being used on the Java client side, when you `close()` the file it may be attempting to close an active FTP session.  This could involve exchanging network packets with the remote server, and if there is a network problem or the server has died, then that could take "a long time" ... depending on how long network timeouts have been set to, etc.

It could also be something like this:

- [Java HttpURLConnection InputStream.close() hangs (or works too long?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378908/java-httpurlconnection-inputstream-close-hangs-or-works-too-long)

My recommendation you be to capture a thread stacktrace while a connection is hung in `close()` and then delve into the Java codebase to figure out where exactly it is hung.  (There are too many possible places for a problem to occur to investigate this without concrete evidence.)

Also try removing the GZIPInputStream from the stack to see if that makes any difference.

Finally, if you come back to us with more evidence, please tell us the precise Java version you are using and the real URL of the FTP server.